# How to get a value in controller from get method and return it back to another view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

The problem looks basic but it is really painful!
I'm using get method and getting value in controller and I want the same value to return in another view.
How can I do that???
Please help!!!
This is my function from controller:

```
public function guest(){
      if (Input::get('Cash On Delivery')){
        $get = Input::get('Cash On Delivery');
        return Redirect::to('guest/guestview/'.$get);
      }
```

Comment: I figured it out bro!
Thanks :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with regards to your answer, using `$_REQUEST` directly is not Laravel's way of doing things :(

I believe this is better

```
public function guest(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->payment_method == ('Cash On Delivery'))
    {
         return view('guest/guestview', ['guest'=>$request->payment_method]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys, I figured it out, 
Just do this below.

```
public function guest(Request $request){
      if ($request->payment_method == ('Cash On Delivery')){
        $get = $_REQUEST['payment_method'];
        return view('guest/guestview', compact('get'));
      }
```